# Managing sbt dependencies with git submodules

Tags: java, git, scala, maven, sbt

We're developing two packages `dep` and `proj`. The development of `dep` and `proj` happen in parrallel - i.e. particular versions of `proj` depend on particular versions of `dep`. Since manually updating the the version of `dep` every few commits is tedious, we were using the `-SNAPSHOT` mechanism (version `0.5-SNAPSHOT` of `proj` depends on `0.4-SNAPSHOT` of `dep`). This is far from ideal we don't have the information to build older commits of `proj` any more.

I've tried out sbt's `RootProject` but that breaks publishing `proj` -- the package no longer includes the dependency on `dep`.

Ideally, here's what I want:

1. `proj` uses the source of `dep` directly via a `git-submodule`
2. When publishing `proj` is able to pull dependency information from `dep`'s project  files.
3. Development versions for `dep` include the git SHA that it was build from

I'd get by without `3`. If `2` is difficult, I'd settle for `sbt` complaining loudly when the dependency specified for packaging doesn't match with the git-submodule.

In case it helps, these are the projects:

- `proj`: (develop branch) https://github.com/kframework/kale
- `dep`: (develop branch) https://github.com/kframework/kore

Answer (score 2):

Working backwards:

`3`: can be achieved with [sbt-dynver](https://github.com/dwijnand/sbt-dynver) and configuring your build to publish on every commit/push. [sbt-release-early](https://github.com/scalacenter/sbt-release-early) can simplify this process if you are publishing to bintray.

`2`: `proj` can depend on the `dep` development versions using commit ranges, e.g. `org % dep % 1.0.+` -- however this makes the build less reproducible because the exact dependency is not specified for a given commit and can increase resolution times

`1`: You might be able to keep the `dep` project as `RootProject` within `proj` to simplify parallel development, while setting up the publish task to ensure `dep` is published first.